# How do I stop hearing a radio station through my Marshall MG15DFX?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers, maintenance

I just purchased a used but in good condition Marshall MG15DFX combo amp for practice in my room. Almost immediately I started hearing a local radio station through the amp even when there is no instrument cables plugged in. I have heard this is a shielding issue with the amp and was wondering what wires could be picking up the station so I can shield them up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amp picking up radio stations](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/amp-picking-up-radio-stations)